# How do I get a list of services in JavaScript using osascript?

Tags: javascript, macos, automation, alfred

I have been trying to create a script that will generate an XML structure of the names of all services available. It works fine in Script Editor, but it can not run from the command line. The code I have is:

```
ObjC.import("Cocoa");
ObjC.import("AppKit");


function run(arg) {
    items = $.NSApp.servicesMenu.itemArray;

    list = "<items>";
    count = 0;
    items.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock(function( obj, index, stop ){
        list += "<item uid='Service" + count + "' arg='" + obj.title.UTF8String + "' valid='yes' autocomplete='"  + obj.title.UTF8String + "'><title>" + obj.title.UTF8String + "</title><subtitle>Services Toolbox</subtitle><icon>icon.png</icon></item>";
        count++;
    });

    list += "</items>";

    return list;
}
```

This code will be used in an Alfred Workflow. Any ideas on how to change it?

As far as I can figure, running this in the osascript interpreter does not have a Services menu, but the Script Editor does. How can I get around this to get the list of services?

Comment: What happens when you run it from the command line?

Comment: I get:  listServices.scpt:67:107: execution error: Error on line 6: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$.NSApp.servicesMenu.itemArray') (0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, since the script is being launched via `osascript`, `$.NSApp` won't have access to the service menu.

But, with a little UI scripting, you can find all the menu items through the finder application:

```
function grabFirstNested(arr) {
  if (arr.length <= 0 || !Array.isArray(arr[0])) {
    return arr;
  }

  return grabFirstNested(arr[0]);
}

function run(arg) {

  var sys = Application('System Events');

  var servicesRef = sys.processes['Finder'].menuBars.menuBarItems.whose({
    name: { _contains: 'finder'}
  }, {ignorign: 'case'}).menus.menuItems.whose({
    name: { _contains: 'services'}
  }, {ignoring: 'case'}).menus.menuItems.name;

  var services = grabFirstNested(servicesRef());
  var list = "<items>";
  services.forEach(function(service, index) {
    list += "<item uid='Service" + index + "' arg='" + service + "' valid='yes' autocomplete='"  + service + "'><title>" + service + "</title><subtitle>Services Toolbox</subtitle><icon>icon.png</icon></item>";
  });
  list += "</items>";

  return list;
}
```

This script will access the Finder application through the `System Events` APIs, which give access to UI elements for scripting. Once it has the Finder application, it grabs the `MenuItems` from the "services" menu bar item.

Comment: Hi Steven, Doing those things doesn't help. The problem is that I am trying to access the Services menu of an application, but technically a script is not an application. Therefore, there is no service menu attached to the process. I need to find a way around that and was wondering if anyone else has figured it out.

Comment: Oh wow, sorry totally misunderstood your question. Posting a different answer now.

Comment: @RichardGuay take a look at the re-written answer, and let me know how that works!

Comment: That will not work either. It comes back with:   Error -1728: Can't get object.

Comment: @RichardGuay make sure you have allowed Terminal (or whatever application is launching `osascript`) access to control the computer through System Preferences->Security & Privacy->Privacy->Accessibility.

Comment: @MarkReed, iTerm and Alfred both have accessibility turned on. Therefore, that is not a problem. I never seem to get predictable results when hacking the interface. That was why I was trying to use the Objective C bridge to do the accessing.

Comment: Also, running osascript as root does not help. I do not think it is an accessibility problem.

Comment: @RichardGuay totally understand. Can you try the updated script I just made? I made the searching more flexible so that it just searches by name of objects, not by their position in the array.

Comment: That worked! Thanks. Now, I am trying to understand it!

Comment: Now, how to take one selected and activate it?